# Tomcat 8 Embedded - ContextResource deprecated alternative

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jndi, tomcat8

Trust you well.

I want to migrate my embedded tomcat source code from tomcat 7 to tomcat 8.
But I have problem with *org.apache.catalina.deploy.ContextResource*  and i have no idea to use other way so far.

I believed *org.apache.catalina.deploy* was deprecated in tomcat 8.

Overall Source Code:

```
public class Tomcat8LocalServer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String baseDir = (System.getProperty("basedir") == null ? System.getProperty("user.dir") : System
            .getProperty("basedir")) + "/public_html/epi_html";

    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.enableNaming();
    try {
        Context context = tomcat.addWebapp("/epi", baseDir);

        bindDataSource(context);

        tomcat.getConnector().setPort(Integer.valueOf(System.getProperty("tomcat.embedded.port", "8080")));
    }
    catch (ServletException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("failed to add webapp", ex);
    }

    try {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        tomcat.start();
        System.out.println("[Tomcat embedded] Server started in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
        System.setProperty("tomcat.embedded.enabled", "true");
    }
    catch (LifecycleException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("failed to start tomcat server", ex);
    }
    tomcat.getServer().await();
}

private static void bindDataSource(Context context) {

     ContextResource res = new ContextResource();

    res.setName("jdbc/EPIZIV_DS");
    res.setType("javax.sql.DataSource");

    res.setProperty("username", System.getProperty("tomcat.embedded.datasource.username", "EPIZIV"));
    res.setProperty("password", System.getProperty("tomcat.embedded.datasource.password", "EPIZIV"));
    res.setProperty("driverClassName",
            System.getProperty("tomcat.embedded.datasource.driver", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"));
    res.setProperty("url",
            System.getProperty("tomcat.embedded.datasource.url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"));
    res.setProperty("maxActive", System.getProperty("tomcat.embedded.datasource.max.active", "5"));
    res.setProperty("maxIdle", System.getProperty("tomcat.embedded.datasource.max.idle", "1"));

    context.getNamingResources().addResource(res);
}
```

StackTrace Snapshot:
[image: Stacktrace]

My Questions:

1. Is there any way to replace *org.apache.catalina.deploy.ContextResource* ?
2. How to initialize/bind data source properties into embedded tomcat 8 source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ContextResource](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/descriptor/web/ContextResource.html) can be found in [Tomcat Embedded Core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.30) and its package name should be "org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web". May you check your imports and classpath?

Comment: solved. your suggestion lead me able to fix this.
changed from 'org.apache.catalina.deploy.ContextResource' to
'org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.ContextResource;'
lesson learned:
check your java build path. I don't realized my classpath still pointing to tomcat 7 jar after changed that package.
By the way, thanks @Stefan for swift response.